# API: jquery-serialize-object is required to add form data to an existing data object (Semantic UI)

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, api, semantic-ui

Based on http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#/usage, I think my code actually run.

Here is the code :

```
$('#new-modul').form({
  fields: {
    division: {
      identifier: 'division',
      rules: [
        {
          type   : 'empty',
          prompt : 'Please select division'
        }
      ]
    },
    application: {
      identifier: 'application',
      rules: [
        {
          type   : 'empty',
          prompt : 'Please select application'
        }
      ]
    },
    title: {
      identifier: 'title',
      rules: [
        {
          type   : 'empty',
          prompt : 'Please enter a title'
        }
      ]
    },
    description: {
      identifier: 'description',
      rules: [
        {
          type   : 'empty',
          prompt : 'Please enter description'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
.api({
  url: './ajax/Ticket/new.php',
  method: 'POST',
  serializeForm: true,
  onComplete: function() {
    completeCreateNewModuleAction();
  }
});
```

But maybe something went wrong, so this error appears on my console.

> Error:
>
> API: jquery-serialize-object is required to add form data to an existing data object

And I don't know why.

Comment: Is Jquery included in your project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#/usage, Look on the **Passing Data** section.

In **Routed Form Data**, It tells us that :

> Structured form data requires including [macek's serialize object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object).

But just for your shortcut information, this is the step i do :

**First :**

> **Download JQuery for Serialize Object** in [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object/master/dist/jquery.serialize-object.min.js) and then save to your local file.
>
> Add as internal javascript, so it can lighten your page.

**Second:**

> Include that file to your page :
>
> `<script src="link_to_your_file/jquery.serialize-object.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to include https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object as stated in [docs](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#/usage)

Comment: Thanks, but i have found the solution that day and forgot to publish :)